# HttpClient cant recoqnize the installed certificate for Https

Tags: ssl-certificate, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing a Windows phone 8 application in which i am using the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) to create some soap requests to a web service As far as "http" concerns everything runs properly, but in order to use https i need to use a custom certificate which when i installed on the windows phone device the IE could see the https website just fine.
So the question is:

Why my HttpClient inside the application doesnt recoqnize it and what do i need to do to access it?

Is that even possible?

Comment: It should work for HttpClient. System.Net on the phone goes through WinINET which is the same stack used by IE.  One thing that folks commonly run into is caching on the phone.  Did you make sure to clear the cache after installing the cert?

Comment: @TheESJ you are right it does recoqnize it if its installed. it was a certificate issue all along. Thank you very much for responding though.